# Closed Form of $ \int_{0}^{\pi} x^3\ln^8(2\sin{(x)}) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have need of a closed form expression to this definite integral:

> $$ \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} x^3\ln^8(2\sin{(x)}) dx$$

It does exist apparently. Both limits are problematic for the natural logarithm function in the integrand. WolframAlpha PRO  gives me a result of 624510 which I take to mean 'Big Number' . By changing limits to a tiny amount left of $\pi$ and a tiny amount right of $0$ , I get a wide range of very large values because from the graph it appears the area is unbounded on the right side. That is as far as my efforts have got me, the past few days.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the left side, for example $$\int_0^3 x^3 \ln^8 (2 \sin x) dx=4.14116$$

Comment: Also, is there a reason not to trust the numerical value which Mathematica gives for this integral ($624 ~509.96048245$)?

Comment: I don't know how to compute the integral, but I can say it's finite: $\sin(x)$ vanishes like $x$ at $\pi$, so the integrand can be controlled by something like $x^3 \ln(x)^8$, which is integrable. The bound at zero isn't a problem either since $x^3 \ln^8(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @Yuriy S  How did you get that value? I use Mathematica 10.3.1 and all it gave me was: "The integrand (x^3)[Log[2\Sin[x]]]^8 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with  boundaries {{0,3.14159}}" - I used NIntegrate. Your result agrees nicely with WolframAlpha Pro.

Comment: @BobKadylo, I used NIntegrate with $\pi$ as an upper limit. However, for $3.14159$ the integral also converges, since it's smaller than $\pi$. For $3.1416$ the integral can't be evaluated by NIntegrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $x=\frac{\theta}{2}$ the integral 
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\pi} x^3\ln^8(2\sin{(x)}) \mathrm dx
$$
becomes
$$
I=\frac{1}{2^{12}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \theta^3\ln^8\left(\left|2\sin\left(\tfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|^2\right) \mathrm d\theta=-\frac{1}{2^{12}}\operatorname{Ls}^{(3)}_{12}(\pi/2)
$$
where 
$$
\operatorname{Ls}^{(m)}_{n}(\sigma)=-\int_{0}^{\sigma} \theta^m\ln^{n-m-1}\left(\left|2\sin\left(\tfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|\right) \mathrm d\theta
$$
is the generalized log-sine integral. It involves many advanced tools to be evaluated and I think it's out of your scope.

Comment: http://arminstraub.com/software/lstoli may or may not help.

Comment: @barrycarter in the link you have log-sine integral (only 1 index), not generalized log-sine (2 index)

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment. Agrees nicely with other results. Plouffe's inverter can't find a match.

```
$Version 

9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012) 

NIntegrate[x^3*Log[2*Sin[x]]^8,{x,0,Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
AccuracyGoal -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 40] 

624509.97425476323973864321155907856915353495760746
```